# Send resume to email as attachment

Tags: php, html, file

I have the following form:

```
 <form method="POST" name="email" action="sendemail.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table border=0 cellPadding=5 cellSpacing=10 width=100%>
        <tr>
            <td><label for='position'>Position:</label></td>
            <td><input type=text name=position class=position value="" READONLY size=35 /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for='uploaded_file'>Resume:</label></td>
            <td><input type="file" name="uploaded_file"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colSpan=2 align=center><input class=subbtn type="submit" value="Submit" name='submit' /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colSpan=2><hr /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colSpan=2 align=center style="padding-top: 5px;"><input type=button value="Close Window" class="close" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

and the following sendemail.php:

```
<?php

$uf = $_POST['uploaded_file'];

  $to = "myemail@yahoo.com";
  $subject = "This is subject";
  $message = "This is test message.";
  # Open a file
  $file = fopen( $uf, "r" );
 if( $file == false )
  {
     echo "Error in opening file";
     exit();
  }
  # Read the file into a variable
  $size = filesize($file);
  $content = fread( $file, $size);

  # encode the data for safe transit
  # and insert \r\n after every 76 chars.
  $encoded_content = chunk_split( base64_encode($content));

  # Get a random 32 bit number using time() as seed.
  $num = md5( time() );

  # Define the main headers.
  $header = "From:myemail@yahoo.com\r\n";
  $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
  $header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; ";
  $header .= "boundary=$num\r\n";
  $header .= "--$num\r\n";

  # Define the message section
  $header .= "Content-Type: text/plain\r\n";
  $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding:8bit\r\n\n";
  $header .= "$message\r\n";
  $header .= "--$num\r\n";

  # Define the attachment section
  $header .= "Content-Type:  multipart/mixed; ";
  $header .= "name=\"test.txt\"\r\n";
  $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding:base64\r\n";
  $header .= "Content-Disposition:attachment; ";
  $header .= "filename=\"test.txt\"\r\n\n";
  $header .= "$encoded_content\r\n";
  $header .= "--$num--";

  # Send email now
  $retval = mail ( $to, $subject, "", $header );
  if( $retval == true )
   {
      echo "Message sent successfully...";
   }
   else
   {
      echo "Message could not be sent...";
   }
?>
```

When I try to send the resume using the form, I get the following error:

> Error in opening file

Can someone please tell me where is the issue and how to resolve it.

Comment: Don't build mime emails by hand. Use PHPmailer or Swiftmailer. Both make it trivial and will drastically reduce the amount of mail-handling code you have to write.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uploaded files are not in the $_POST array, they are in the $_FILES array.

So use $_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'] instead of $_POST['uploaded_file']

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php for further implementation of $_FILES.

Please also take care of security problems when uploading files and validate the file with the is_uploaded_file() function in PHP.

Comment: where is the ['tmp_name'] being used? I can just change the POST to FILES?

Comment: tmp_name is the temporary name under which the file is stored on your server.

Comment: `['tmp_name']` is the file path of the temporary file on your server.

Comment: What if i am not looking to upload to my server and instead take the file and email directly? Is that possible? This is the first time I am doing this so will it be possible to help me re-do the script?

Comment: When posting the form to your server the file is always uploaded and stored temporarily. The mail is sent from your server, so it has to be uploaded, you can't send a mail from the client browser in that way. But that's not a problem, the file is also automatically removed after script execution if you don't copy it somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$to = $_POST['toEmail'];
$fromEmail = $_POST['fieldFormEmail'];
$fromName = $_POST['fieldFormName'];
$subject = $_POST['fieldSubject'];

/* GET File Variables */
$tmpName = $_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'];
$fileType = $_FILES['attachment']['type'];
$fileName = $_FILES['attachment']['name'];

/* Start of headers */
$headers = "From: $fromName";

if (file($tmpName)) {
  /* Reading file ('rb' = read binary)  */
  $file = fopen($tmpName,'rb');
  $data = fread($file,filesize($tmpName));
  fclose($file);

  /* a boundary string */
  $randomVal = md5(time());
  $mimeBoundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$randomVal}x";

  /* Header for File Attachment */
  $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n";
  $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" ;
  $headers .= " boundary=\"{$mimeBoundary}\"";

  /* Multipart Boundary above message */
  $message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" .
  "--{$mimeBoundary}\n" .
  "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" .
  "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" .
  $message . "\n\n";

  /* Encoding file data */
  $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));

  /* Adding attchment-file to message*/
  $message .= "--{$mimeBoundary}\n" .
  "Content-Type: {$fileType};\n" .
  " name=\"{$fileName}\"\n" .
  "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" .
  $data . "\n\n" .
  "--{$mimeBoundary}--\n";
}

$flgchk = mail ("$to", "$subject", "$message", "$headers");

if($flgchk){
  echo "<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
        alert('Success');
        window.location = 'index.php';
    </script>";
 }
else{
  echo "<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
        alert('Message failed');
        window.location = 'index.php';
    </script>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use === instead of ==

```
if( $file === false )
```

or

```
 if( !$file )
```

Comment: `!$file` is literally equivalent to `$file == false`. File handles will never be `0`, so the strict equality test is not necessary.